# Cannot restore data using Postgres WAL files

Tags: transaction-log, recovery, postgresql-9.1

I'm a newbie at PostgreSQL.
I'm trying to setup a streaming replication (postgresql 9.1).
And I want to test backup & restore on local.
I also made backup files successfully (I think so) by using `pg_basebackup`
But cannot restore data.
Here is how I set my database up.

- Postgres on server1 (master)

  Configure file: /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/postgresql.conf

  ```
   # WRITE AHEAD LOG
   wal_level = hot_standby

   # - Archiving -
   archive_mode = on
   archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/wal-archive/%f'

   # - Master Server -
   max_wal_senders = 5
   wal_keep_segments = 32

   # - Standby Servers -
   hot_standby = on
  ```
- Start master and insert some data
- Postgres on server2 (slave)

  Configure file: /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/postgresql.conf (content is same as master)
- Create recovery.conf file on slave

  ```
   // vi /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/recovery.conf
   standby_mode = 'on'
   primary_conninfo = 'host={master_hostname} port=5432 user=repl_user password={my_password}'
  ```
- Start slave => and data is automatically synced with master
- Create WAL backup

  ```
   // slave
   service postgresql-9.1 stop
   rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/*
   su - postgres
   pg_basebackup -h {master_hostname} -p 5432 -U repl_user -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data --xlog --checkpoint=spread --progress
  ```
- WAL files is generated in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/wal-archive` on master after `pg_basebackup` is executed in slave

  ```
   // something like this
   000000070000000000000013
   000000070000000000000014
   000000070000000000000015
   000000070000000000000015.00000020.backup
  ```
- Drop one table (master)

  ```
   DROP TABLE {table_name}
  ```
- Restore that dropped table using WAL files (master)

  ```
   service postgresql-9.1 stop 
   vi /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/recovery.conf

   // add this line to recovery.conf
   restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/wal-archive/%f %p'
  ```
- Start master again

  ```
   service postgresql-9.1 start
  ```

But that dropped table is not restored on master. I don't know why.
I also tried to add some other option, but everything is not worked.

```
recovery_target_time = '2020-10-29 08:20:00 UTC'
recovery_target_inclusive = false
```

Please help on how to restore data using WAL files.

If I accidentally drop a table on master, how can I restore it using WAL files? Which configuration should I setup on recovery.conf file? Is just write restore_command in recovery.conf file and start postgres again make server restore the lastest backup point data?

Comment: Shouldn't your recovery.conf file be located on your slave?

Comment: You need to restore a basebackup taken before you dropped the table! WAL only contains changes made since that backup. You can't go backwards with WAL.

Comment: NB You are using an absolutely *ancient* version of Postgres. It last received a maintenance update 4 years ago and is a staggering 9 releases behind the latest  supported release.

Comment: @Colin'tHart my company use this old version of Postgres. My duty is maintaining it and make sure nothing wrong happen. Problem now is wal-archive folder's file is too much and it takes much server's storage. I can remove it with pg_archivecleanup. But if something wrong happen, I need to restore data to the old state.

Comment: @Earl if I put recovery.conf in slave server, can I recognize WAL file in master server and restore data base on it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on how backup and recovery works. WAL doesn't let you go *backwards* in time, only forwards.

When restoring you would normally restore your data files from your backup (eg one taken with `pg_basebackup`). That will get you back to the moment the backup was started. If you want to go further in time, you need to supply the WAL files for changes made since the backup. In your `recovery_conf` you can specify to restore to the time just before the table was dropped using `recovery_target_time =`  as you have done.

Normally such a restore would be done in a secondary environment. You would then export the dropped table(s) or modified data and import that into your production database (or run update/insert/delete statements to change the state of the database). That way you don't lose other modifications made since the table was dropped.

Comment: sorry for late response, so how can i restore data using data files from backup (that is taken with pg_basebackup)? Is that the file end with '.backup' in wal-archive folder? Can you give me some command, or reference link. It is so appropriate.

Comment: I have no idea how your backups are structured. You need to find a way to restore the Postgres data directory -- that needs to be in your backups somewhere.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to ask. I don't know to restore data on slave base on WAL files that stored in master. I understand your explanation about how backup is working. But if I write recovery.conf file like I described above, it seems that not relevant to master at all. My Postgres data is stored in '/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/'. After run pg_basebackup on slave server, data is all copied to slave server. Is that good for backup part?